# Final binary size: constexpr variable vs constexpr function

Tags: c++, constexpr

First, I have read this very informative [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16296215/6153683) about stylistic difference between defining a constexpr variable vs constexpr function. My question is more related with the final size of the binary when using these two. Consider this code:

```
// approach 1
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  static constexpr char name[] = "mickey";
};

// approach 2
template <typename T>
struct bar
{
  static constexpr const char* getName() { return "mickey"; }
};

const char* func1() { return foo<int>::name; }
const char* func2() { return foo<double>::name; }

const char* func3() { return bar<int>::getName(); }
const char* func4() { return bar<double>::getName(); }
```

Look at this code in this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/8MxrxQ) link as well. While approach 1 returns different copies of name, approach 2 returns only one copy for all the different instantiations for different T. Infact, when I created 100 different types approach 2 led to a considerably smaller binary. Was wondering if anyone has experienced something similar.

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking us to confirm that functions take up space in your executable image? Well, yes, yes they do.

Comment: Replied on the best answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, those two approaches aren't really the same. There are things you can do with `foo<T>::name` that you cannot do with `bar<T>::getName()`: I can take a pointer to it and I can take a reference to it. That ability prevents different `foo<T>::name`s from being the same.

But with `getName()`, there's no such issue. You just get a prvalue - you can't take its address. The different `bar<T>::getName` functions themselves have to be different, but not the underlying storage.

Comment: While true, doesn't really help if your goal is to minimize the size of the executable, to which the existence of this question attests. Not your fault — it's entirely unclear as to what the question _is_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I interpreted the question as "why is there a difference?"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Apologies for being unclear in the question. Barry's reply is exactly what I was seeking for. (I reached there via a convoluted way though)

Comment: You can't odr use `foo<T>::name` being it a `constexpr`. Am I wrong? You can't _take a pointer or a reference to it_ indeed.

Comment: `struct S { static constexpr int v = 42;
}; int main() { const int *p = &S::v;
}` results with an undefined reference to `S::v` when the linker takes its part to the game. Because you *can't* take the address of a `constexpr` variable. Of course, unless you add `constexpr int S::v;` somewhere, but to odr use a `constexpr` doesn't make much sense indeed.

Comment: @skypjack That has nothing to do with constexpr. You just didn't add a definition.

Comment: @Barry You need a definition, because you can't odr-use a constexpr variable otherwise. That is the point of the first comment. We are in a loop. :-D

Comment: @skypjack Again, that has nothing to do with constexpr. You can't odr-use anything without a definition. Constexpr variables can have definitions.

Comment: @Barry Well, right, but we are speaking about constexpr variables!! What I'm saying is that you can _use_ them, but you cannot odr-use them without a definition (and we agree on that, let's use the right terms) that is quite uncommon for a constexpr. On the other side, from the answer it seems that you can take the address of a constexpr as mentioned in the OP's example, that is not possible (they have not a definition). So, at least, it's worth to mention it, otherwise the reader (a not so expert one) could misunderstand. That's all.