# Advantage of replacing static const members with static member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, static, constants

I came across code like this from a programmer I highly respect:

```
class BigClass {
  using MyId = uint32_t;
  static constexpr MyId INVALID_ID() { return  std::numeric_limits<MyId>::max();};
  class SmallClass {
    /* Constructor, etc. */
    MyId id = INVALID_ID(); /* Default value */
  };
};
```

Is there any obvious advantage to defining INVALID_ID() as a function instead of as a static const variable?

The question [static constexpr variable vs function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287776/static-constexpr-variable-vs-function) is precisely the same question I had (I used `uint32_t` as an example, but I find the question interesting for other types as well). However, I am not satisfied with the answer to that question. After reading some of the answers here, I believe there are more advantages to using functions than the ability to be easily templated.

Comment: Well since it is not a static member variable it does not need to be defined outside the class.

Comment: @NathanOliver IIRC static constants do not need a definition until they are ODR-used.

Comment: @Quentin Typo fixed.  They may use it in that context.

Comment: *"However, I am not satisfied with the answer to that question."* Ask for clarification or raise a bounty over at the dupe then. No point in having satisfactory answers here and leaving the earlier variant of this question with "poor" answers. (And yes I know you don't have the rep yet, you would need to earn some.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason is that in this form, there is no need for defining the static member outside the class, which in cases where the class is implemented inside a header can be undesirable.

A second reason is extensibility, you could one day want your invalid ID to do some other constexpr logic in its initialization, other than calling one constexpr function like max

Comment: Well, since this is a constant of integral type, there's no need to define it outside the class anyway. Obviously, it is not supposed to be usable as lvalue and as long as it is not used a lvalue, no definition is requred.

Comment: It's still good practice in my opinion

Comment: Quote the opposite, if the static constant is intended to be used as rvalue only, then *not* defining it is a good practice - it prevents abusing it as an lvalue. Making the definition optional was a significant and long-awaited addition to C++ spec.

Comment: I meant good practice to put it in a function.

Answer (score 2):

I can only see one true difference beyond simple coding usages: a static const variable needs to be defined only if it is odr used (used in a function taking a ref for example...). The problem is that if this rule is not respected, you get a link time error, and programmers can waste time searching after what the problem really is.

When you use a function that way, and you try to pass it as a function call to a function needing a ref, a compile time error will immediately spot on the face of the programmer, with an explicit error message. So I would say that it is more future maintainers friendly...

Comment: A call to an undefined function can be compiled just like a usage of a declared static global. Both result in linker errors.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with thread safety and the static initialization order fiasco. If there were two interdependent static variables that are defined in separate translation units (one needs the value of the other to construct itself) there is no way of guaranteeing the order in which they will be initialized.

Using a wrapper function and C++11's guarantee that the compiler will place the necessary thread locks around its initialization, a function local static will make concurrent calls to that function wait for the variable to be initialized before execution continues.

Comment: should you change forget to do in *This has to forget with thread safety and the static initialization order fiasco*?

Comment: Yes indeed, phone keyboards haven't gotten much better at guessing what I want to type...

Comment: Okay.  I just wanted to check in case you mashed to different sentences together.

Comment: Unlikely. This question seem to target a specific situation where the constant value is intended to be a compile-time constant (an Integral Constant Expressions). Thread sagety and initialization order is not an issue.

Comment: You confuse static initialization with dynamic. No dynamic initialization is involved here.

Answer (score 1):

One problem people try to solve by replacing class static constant members with functions is linker errors.

For example:

```
struct A {
    static constexpr int a = 1;
};

void foo(int const&);

foo(A::a); // Linker error: A::a.
```

The correct solution is to not take a pointer or reference to `A::a` (if providing the out-of-line definition of `A::a` is undesirable):

```
void foo(int);
```

Comment: You can take the pointer. Just just have to define `A::a`.

Comment: @NO_NAME Defining `A::a` may be undesirable.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any advantage. I'd rather see `INVALID_ID` declared as a const (constexpr) than a function because the function call makes the reader wonder what kind of computation is going on.

Comment: Similar question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287776/static-constexpr-variable-vs-function?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The declaration is for a constexpr function which have zero dynamic computation. Id rather see a constexpr anything on any other declaration.